# Arrays in NEO4j using Neography+Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, neo4j, neography

I am running a rake process that imports my data into Neo4j. It's all fine until arrays come up. Here's a sample:

{:spelling=>"the", :letters=>["T","H","E"], :length=>2, :rank=>1, :part_of_speech=>"article"}

Here's the ruby code for importing it that fails:

node = @neo.create_unique_node("words", "spelling_phonemes", a[:spelling]+','+a[:phonemes],
                                     {"spelling" => a[:spelling], 
                                     "length" => a[:length],
                                     "letters" => a[:letters].split(','),
                                     "rank" => a[:rank],
                                     "part_of_speech" => a[:part_of_speech]})

Here's the error:
Unknown property type on: [T, H, E], class java.util.ArrayList

It's working fine on locally. What gives! From reading around, it seems likes ArrayList might be the issue as only type Array works. If that's the case, how do I ensure that the ruby array is casted/converted properly as a Java Array ?! Thanks!

Also, using neo4j 2.0 locally and Heroku is 1.8.1 I think.

Comment: For now, I've removed arrays and am just parsing a string into an array. It's not ideal (though you may think so looking at my trivial example above), but I'd like to still know in the future how to handle this if you come across this question.

Answer (score 0):

1.8.1 is ancient and probably not compatible with any recent neography versions... If you want a remotely hosted version that is current (on 2.0) try http://www.graphenedb.com